# Map Size when Testing React Leaflet

Tags: react-leaflet

I'm trying to test a custom react-leaflet component.  It grabs the map element and uses a filter to get the number of elements visible at the current zoom level:

```js
const visible = allPoints.filter(p => map.getBounds().contains(p));
```

This code works fine in the application, but when I try to test with Jest & Enzyme, the filter always returns 0 elements, regardless of zoom level.  Poking at it a bit, I discovered that `map.getSize()` always returns 0x0 and `map.getBounds()` returns the same point for the southwest and northeast corners, which explains why it can't really contain any other points.

Is this just a bug in Enzyme or Leaflet or is there something that I need to do to set the map size explicitly?

```js
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { MapContext } from "../../../context";
import MarkersShown from "../markers-shown";
import { Map } from "react-leaflet";
import { mockParsed, mockCenter, mockData } from "./__data__";

describe("MarkersShown Tests", () => {
    it("renders the total asset count", async () => {
        const parsed = mockParsed;
        const center = mockCenter;
        let wrapper;
        await act(async () => {
            wrapper = mount(
                <MapContext.Provider value={mockData}>
                    <Map zoom={parsed.z} center={center} style={{ height: "100px", width: "100px" }}>
                        <MarkersShown />
                    </Map>
                </MapContext.Provider>
            );
        });
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual(
            expect.stringMatching("Markers Shown of 3")
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because jsdom doesn't support `clientWidth`/`clientHeight`, which `getSize` relies on.

A terrible hack to work around it:

```js
import { Map, Point } from 'leaflet'

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(Map.prototype, 'getSize').mockImplementation(() => new Point(500, 500))
})
```